# Facebook Object API -- created as article, thinks it's website

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook's Object API to create my own custom open graph object. The object created itself just fine, with code like follows:

```
FB.api(
    "https://graph.facebook.com/app/objects/article?access_token=token|secret",
    "POST",
    {
        "object": {
            "og:url": url,
            "og:title": title,
            "og:image": image
        }               
    },
    function(response) {
        // handle response
    }
);
```

I then prompt a share dialog to open, like so:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: 'news.reads',
    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
        article: 'https://graph.facebook.com/app/website/my_object_id'
    })  
}, function(response) {
    // handle response
});
```

The dialog opens, but it gives this error:

"Object at URL https://graph.facebook.com/app/website/my_object_id has og:type of 'website'.
The property 'article' requires an object of og:type 'article'."

But didn't I just specify when creating that I was creating an article? Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

I'm just trying to create opengraph objects dynamically instead of using meta tags on an html page -- I have a list of items on the page that I want to allow the user to share as opengraph objects.

Comment: What do you get when you read the details of your object back from the API? And why are you using a URL to share, instead of the object id? And where did you get the URL `https://graph.facebook.com/app/website/…` from anyway? What is `website` doing in that URL?

Comment: @CBroe: It appears I was mistaken -- I put in the object Id instead of the url for the article property, and the share dialog showed the article just like it should. I guess I had misunderstood the docs. If you care to post using the id as the answer, I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To post an object created via API using the Share dialog you need to pass the object id you got back from the API when creating the object, not a URL.

(A URL would be an appropriate parameter when you want to post an Open Graph object that is hosted elsewhere on an external domain.)